# SharePoint Designer workflow executing same lines\steps multiple time in single instance

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

I am working SharePoint 2010 workflow. I am facing an issue.
**Problem:**
1) I have few workflows running on different situation
2) Out of all workflows one is set to execute on "Item Created"
3) This workflow having some lines to execute and then create an item and then wait for a change in field value.
4) **Expectation:** This should create one instance and execute the lines\steps only once and wait for field change.
5) **Actual Out-Come:** The workflow is executing the lines\steps three times in a single instance.
6) The workflow history is showing the three time execution of all lines\steps using log to history.
7) It is a SPD workflow so there is no while loop. but it behaving like while loop.
8) On create Item, we are creating task, so it is creating three tasks. It is sending three emails and also we are appending text in title so text is appended three times.

I did a lot of research but not able to find the solution.
Please help. Its Urgent.